# Read data from .txt file or .cs file and update the file contents in sql database using python

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

How to write automation script for below example:

already tables are available only read the data from .txt file and and update in the tables columns in a sequence.

ex: file1.txt
a,b,c,b,e

DB:
TABLE NAME:SATYA
COLUMN NAME:1|2|3|4|5

UPDATED DB should be:
COLUMN NAME:1|2|3|4|5
UPDATED VALUES:a b c b e

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask. What have you tried and where specifically are you having issues?

Comment: Is there a reason for the JavaScript and Java tags?  Would you be able to remove them if they're not relevant please?

Comment: asking how to write automation script for mentioned example in python using robot framework

Answer (score 0):

You put robotframework tag, so i guess that you want to do it in python, but call the function from robot.
Why you want to develop this function in python and lose all robot's abstraction?
DatabaseLibrary was made to work with db, already from documentation is possible to understand how to make a keword to update db.

Link to library with example below:
https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html